# Apple Developer Portal: Adding a Services ID does not allow me to select "Sign In With Apple"

Tags: ios, xcode, sign-in-with-apple

I have a personal (paid) developer account I use to build a new application. This application neesd "Sign In With Apple" so I configured my developer account in Xcode, a unique bundle ID and checked the "Sign In With Apple" checkbox in the "Signing & Capabilities" tab. I even tried not to check it and see if it would become available that way, to no avail.

The problem is I have the App ID for my given Bundle, the "Sign In With Apple" checkbox is checked there but I cannot add a Service ID for the same Bundle. Also there's not "Sign In With Apple" checkbox when I try to create the service. When I continue anyway, I get the error

```
An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value

An App ID with Identifier 'my.app.bundle' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

I'm not sure what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Bundle ID was the same as my app's. It should be slightly different, like `my.app.bundle.appleauth`. Also this checkbox didn't become available until I saved it first.